# Module: Set default values of fields dynamically

Tags: joomla-3.x, module

I am having different environments development and production for a website and each of its database varies.

I have created a module which will connect to an external database. But now I want to make it dynamic like if the environment is `dev` then automatic the fields must be entered according to dev and if its `prod` then details must be according to prod.

Following is my code:

**mod_test.xml**

```
<fieldset name="basic">
    <field name="db_hostname" type="text" default="" label="Host Name" description="Enter the Database Host Name" />
    <field name="db_port" type="text" default="" label="Port" description="Enter the Database Port Number" />
    <field name="db_name" type="text" default="" label="Database Name" description="Enter the Database Name" />
    <field name="db_user" type="text" default="" label="Database Username" description="Enter the Database Username" />
    <field name="db_password" type="password" default="" label="Database Password" description="Enter the Database Password" />
</fieldset>
```

Currently, each time I have to change the db details in the administrator according the environments. Therefore I want to make it dynamic and to pre-fill the data according to different environments. Kindly, let me know how to proceed on this.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution to my problem :) `custom_fields`

Following is my code:

```
<fieldset name="basic" addfieldpath="/modules/mod_test/models/fields">
    <field name="db_hostname" type="Dbhost" default="" label="Host Name" description="Enter the Database Host Name" />
</fieldset>
```

**in models/fields/dbhost.php**

```
<?php 
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
//define environment
define('ENV', getenv('ENV'));
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');
class JFormFieldDbhost extends JFormField {
protected $type = 'Dbhost';
public function getInput() {
 if(defined('ENV')){
  switch(ENV){
   case 'dev':
   $host= 'devhost';
   break;
   case 'prod':
   $host = 'prodhost';
   break;
   default:
   $host = 'localhost';
   break;
   }
 }
  return '<input type="text" id="'.$this->id.'" name="'.$this->name.'"    value="'.$host.'">';             
}
}
?>
```